# Cocoa - Application Freezes During Loading Data From XML

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsprogressindicator

I am loading a huge amount of data from an XML file. This data is "freezing" the application. I would like to display a progress bar in the time that the data is being loaded.

How would I know that much of the operation has been completed so that I can change the percentage shown of the progress bar? Thanks. [answered]

Edited: The main problem is that the application freezes during loading due to the large amount of data to be parsed. Some have suggested using a background thread to load and parse the data.. Is that viable?

Comment: Also, the problem with "freezing" is that if I switch to another application and then back to the app in question, the app will not display until the whole process of loading is complete... which would make the whole progress bar irrelevant. Is there any way to combat that? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is a desktop application, specially a preference app for the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file into memory @ 4k at a time? Show the process of loaded bytes vs file size?

Additionally figure out total number of lines and what current line your parser is on.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSXMLParser/lineNumber

Assuming you are using NSXMLParser

The "freezing" is coming from you doing the load/parsing on the main thread. If you can us GCD trying doing a dispatch_async ( ) and sending updates to your main thread on completion and to update progress.

Comment: Where did the 4k figure come from please?

Comment: Just a buffer size I tend to start with for huge file loads. Try identifying your bottleneck, is it file load? My guess it's parsing your xml and creating objects from it. Try producing the progress of your xml parser first.

Comment: Can you provide some reference for using GCD? Thanks.

Comment: I've read up on GCD (grand central dispatch). Basically it's Apple's way of saying threads right? I've never used threads in this language so it's quite a whole new area  have to get into.. Thanks for any further help that you might give me.

Comment: GCD is easier than worrying about threads for most users. http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2009/09/guide-to-blocks-grand-central-dispatch.html is a really good reference for knowing it all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NSXML parser,

```
NSUInteger count = [[rootElement nodesForXPath:@"//Video" error:&error] count];
//this will give you the number of elements
//then after parsing each element, calculate the percentage of elements parsed. 

//i.e. num_of_elements_parsed/total_no_elements*100;
//based on this value, use a del;egate method to update your NSProgressIndicator 
// in this method increment the  num_of_elements_parsed counter
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"resident"]) {

        self.count += 1; 

    }
}
```

Comment: Ic, that makes a lot of sense thanks. However, I am still having an issue that the screen is 'freezing' on me, and therefore updating the progress bar only would have no effect on the user - he would only see a 100% progress bar when the screen get back to normal.. Thanks though!

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740048/iphone-parsing-multiple-xml-with-nsxmlparser-in-background-disturbing-each-othe